# ООП PHP - создание объекта класса в методе класса

Tags: php, ооп

Использую CI.
Есть класс:

```
class Profile extends Auth {
    public function Edit(){
        $editObj = new EditProfile($this->typeAccount, $this->idUser);
    }    
}


class EditProfile extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct($type, $idUser) {
        $this->typeAccount = $type;
        $this->idUser = $this->idUser = $idUser;
        $this->ValidationPOST();
    }
}
```

В классе `Profile` есть публичный метод `Edit()`, в котором создается объект класса `EditProfile`, дальше все управление передается этому классу.

Вопрос в том, что при вызове конструктора `parent::__construct();` родителя в классе `EditProfile` возникает ошибка:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Rediska in Unknown on line 0

Это говорит о том, что ранее в классе `Profile` уже один раз был создан экземпляр класса `Rediska`.

Возможно, я ошибся в структуре взаимодействия классов. Буду признателен Вашей помощи и рассуждений.

Comment: ну и где ваша редиска в предоставленном куске кода?

Comment: по данным примерам ничего не понятно.

Comment: Она подгружается как библиотека через основной класс ядра CI

Comment: > Это говорит о том, что ранее в классе Profile уже один раз был создан экземпляр класса Rediska.

Это говорит о том, что к этому моменту класс Rediska уже был объявлен, но почему-то объявляется второй раз. Путем нехитрых логических умозаключений могу сказать, что там где-то фигурирует `include/require 'Rediska.php'` (вместо адекватного автозагрузчика) или `class_exists()` без второго аргумента, выставленного в false, что и портит всю малину.

Вечно [ваш](http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110718154106/scrubs/images/5/5a/6x9-Laughing_Cox.jpg).

Comment: Ответ - супер! Профессионально! А адекватный автозагрузчик - это как? Можете подсказать? В моем случае Вы оказались правы, у меня конструкция include

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk

> А адекватный автозагрузчик - это как? 

это такой, с которым вообще include и require придется забыть, потому что он будет сам отрабатывать по `new Class`, производя поиск по имени класса. Подробнее в доках по [spl_autoload_register()](http://php.net//manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php), advanced level - [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) / [PSR-4](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader.md).

Comment: Сейчас ознакомлюсь - спасибо!

Comment: Честно сказать, не понял, как работать с этой функцией. В примере приводится обвертка, где не понятно, какой класс подгружается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В примере приводится обвертка, где не понятно, какой класс подгружается

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});
```

Вот эти три строчки непонятны? Автозагрузчиком устанавливается функция, которая берет имя класса и пихает его в хардкодную конструкцию, выходит что-то типа `include 'classes/Rediska.class.php';`. Стоп, погодите с аплодисментами, я еще не закончил.

Автозагрузчик имеет такой расклад: он не знает, что нерадивый пользователь в него засунет в очередной раз, но знает, где лежат файлы классов, знает, что такого класса может не существовать, и знает, что он может быть не один в системе, поэтому сразу инклюдить отсутствующий файл и кудахтать на всю систему об ошибке он не должен. Все, что он должен - предположить местонахождение класса и подключить, если существует, заткнуться, если нет.

```
class GlobalAutoloader
{
    protected static $sourceDirs = array();
    public static function registerSource($directory)
    {
        static::$sourceDirs[] = $directory;
    }
    public static function loadClass($className)
    {
        foreach (static::$sourceDirs as $dir) {
            // рассчитываем вероятное местонахождение файла
            $filePath = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$className.'.php';
            // не нашли файл? игнорируем и молчим. нашли файл? прерываем цикл.
            if (file_exists($filePath)) {
                include $filePath;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('GlobalAutoloader::loadClass');
```

С неймспейсами все еще проще. Во-первых, для каждого неймспейса можно указать свой собственный сорс, во-вторых, есть композер, который хоть и рассчитан на зависимости, может и просто посчитать автозагрузчик для собственного проекта, в-третьих, мне лень это расписывать.

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь стало ясно. Только, я не вижу как передать для spl_autoload_register нужны мне класс, в данном случае Rediska.php, у меня многие классы по разным папкам. Неужто, он найдет и подключит все?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk предполагая следующее содержание dummy-проекта:

    /var/www/superproject
      external/Rediska.php
      components
        BlackJack.php
        GlobalAutoloader.php
      models/Hooker.php

будет достаточно такого бутстрап-кода (предположим, что это bootstrap.php в /var/www/superpoject) :

    $basePath = dirname(__FILE__);
    require $basePath.'/components/GlobalAutoloader.php';
    spl_autoload_register('GlobalAutoloader::loadClass');
    GlobalAutoloader::registerSource($basePath.'/external');
    GlobalAutoloader::registerSource($basePath.'/components');

->

Comment: .

    GlobalAutoloader::registerSource($basePath.'/models');

после этого следующий код должен отработать сам по себе:

    $hooker = new Hooker;
    $blackJack = new BlackJack;
    $rediska = new Rediska;

(я его не тестил, поэтому что-то может пойти *не так*. но сама работа с классами таким образом вполне достижима)

Comment: Все таки достану вас до конца, у меня есть такой конструктор, может проще через class_exists будет?

 function __construct(){
        $options = array(
                'namespace' => '',
                'servers'   => array(
                        array( 'host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 6379 )
                )
        );
        include( APPPATH.'libraries/Rediska.php' );
        include( APPPATH.'libraries/Rediska/Key.php' );
    }

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk пока в проекте одно такое место - да. Но вообще надо все делать по уму.

Comment: Нашел готовый пример для Codeigniter:
http://codeigniter-blog.de/285/codeigniter-autoloading-classes/
Вопрос вот в чем:

     spl_autoload_register('Rediska');
spl_autoload_register('Key');
$this->_redis = new Rediska($options);

Будет ли правильным такой вызов?

Comment: Можно тогда пример, как это сделать с class_exists?
Дело в том, что экземпляр класса Key создается, по всей видимости а классе Rediska.

     include( APPPATH.'libraries/Rediska.php' );
include( APPPATH.'libraries/Rediska/Key.php' );
$this->_redis = new Rediska($options);

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, я честно не знаю что у вас там за проект и не хочу разбираться в нем. Вам нужен один include файла класса, не больше и не меньше (кстати, вы слышали про `include_once()`?), как именно он осуществляется - не так уж и важно.